# Unable to import project with lsp/lsp-mode, persistent completing-read popup message

Tags: spacemacs, lsp-mode, lsp, clojure

I recently had to redo my development setup, I'm using Clojure and clojure-lsp as lsp server, and every time I open a project file I get the message `"x" file is not part of any project" and gives me the option to import the project root (i), import interactively (I), etc.
I always choose the first, but right after that I get this pop up message:

[image: pop up message displayed with completing-read]

When choosing Retry it just keeps coming up and it only goes away when I choose "Ignore" but then the lsp server seems to never start. I get a message saying `LSP :: clojure-lsp:23852 initialized successfully in folders: ...` but I don't get any of the lsp-server/mode functionality.

Ocasionally I've seen this message appear: `Error while reading file system events: Resource temporarily unavailable` this seems to happen when I execute `lsp-workspace-restart`, although it's not consistent, sometimes it shows and sometimes it doesn't.

This keeps happening every time I restart emacs and open a file from the same project, seems like the project is never imported by lsp?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this I realized I was selecting a project root that didn't have a valid `deps.edn` file and so `cljojure-lsp` was failing. So the solution is to be sure to select a project root with a valid `deps.edn`/`project.clj`/etc. This will depend on the type of project you're working on.

I still have to point out the fact that (in my case) Spacemacs did not show the function/command being executed that was resulting in an error, which is why it kept showing that Retry/Ignore dialog.